# LDAP authentication using PHP laravel 4.2 framework

Tags: php, laravel, ldap

I am relatively new to Laravel framework.I would like to use authentication through LDAP system in one of my project.
I followed the steps mention in http://packalyst.com/packages/package/dsdevbe/ldap-connector.
But the connection is not successful.As per the documentation in ldap.php contains five parameters

```
 'account_suffix'        =>  "",
 'domain_controllers'    =>  array(""), // Load balancing domain controllers
 'base_dn'               =>  ''
'admin_username'        =>  '',    // Just needs to be an valid account to query other users if they exists
'admin_password'        =>  ''
```

But in my case I don't have the admin_username and admin_password.Is these parameters are mandatory?

In my case I just want to authenticate the user and retrieve their roles from LDAP. Please help me to resolve this. Any other suggestions also highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin forms a bridge between Laravel authentication system and the ADLDAP library.

The ldap file contains the configuration settings needed for ADLDAP (see [doc](http://adldap.sourceforge.net/wiki/doku.php?id=documentation_configuration)). 
In the documentation it says that these parameters are optional (Default: null)

You can remove this but you will have less permissions.

> By default, adLDAP will perform your searches with permissions of the user account you have called with authenticate(). You may wish to specify an account with higher privileges to perform privileged operations.

For the next question

> I just want to authenticate the user and retrieve their roles from LDAP

The authentication is possible but the retrieval of the role is not implemented yet. This could be an improvement for the plugin.

But currently I'm lacking time for further development.